# Why isn't zero date when compared to null, null?

Tags: mysql, date, null

1. `SELECT NULL;` prints

   > <null>
2. `SELECT CAST('0000-00-00' AS DATE);` prints

   > <null>
3. `SELECT NULL IS NULL;` prints

   > 1
4. `SELECT CAST('0000-00-00' AS DATE) IS NULL;` prints

   > 0

Why isn't the result of the 4th statement `1`?

Tested using DataGrip while connecting to MySQL 5.7.17 on windows.
[image]

Comment: When I try the second statement, it prints `0000-00-00`, not `<null>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [kiks73](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1049569/kiks73), [iamsankalp89](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8164333/iamsankalp89) and [moscas](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/143976/136044) for their answers ([kiks73's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46583742/5132301) - [iamsankalp89's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46583788/5132301) - [moscas's answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/143976/136044)) which helped me find the solution/ explanation for the odd behavior that I've encountered.

The reason for the odd behavior was how **JDBC driver** which is used by DataGrip would handle a zero date.

It would receive the date as zeros from the database then **convert it to null**.

[image: DataGrip connection and JDBC settings]

That would result in DataGrip reading zero dates as nulls because of the JDBC conversion.

[image: DataGrip Query Result]

Howevenr, because its done at the JDBC layer (not the database layer) the database doesn't see those values as nulls.

To test for that, i ran the database connection and the query through mysql shell, which would print zeros instead of nulls.

[image: MySQL Shell Query Result]

Answer (score 1):

Because the 2. isn't true:

```
SELECT CAST('0000-00-00' AS DATE); prints
```

> 0000-00-00

It doesn't print

> NULL

[image]

Answer (score 1):

4th statement show the result 0000-00-00

In mysql Only null is null. Everything else is not, so that it returns 1

[image: Updated Result]

Comment: In mysql Only null is null. Everything else is not, so that it returns 1

Comment: but the left hand side evaluates to null, according to statement 2 (in my testing)

Answer (score 0):

**Tested in Ubuntu mysql:**

```
SELECT CAST('0000-00-00' AS DATE) ;
```

The value of the above query is null,

```
mysql> SELECT CAST('0000-00-00' AS DATE);
+----------------------------+
| CAST('0000-00-00' AS DATE) |
+----------------------------+
| NULL                       |
+----------------------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

```
SELECT CAST('0000-00-00' AS DATE) IS NULL;
```

In the above query, you are trying to check the value is null using **IS NULL** function and the answer is **True** so only it's displaying the value as 1.

```
mysql> SELECT CAST('0000-00-00' AS DATE) IS NULL;
+------------------------------------+
| CAST('0000-00-00' AS DATE) IS NULL |
+------------------------------------+
|                                  1 |
+------------------------------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

**While testing using others,**

```
SELECT CAST('0000-00-00' AS DATE) ;
```

The value of the above query won't display as **NULL**,

```
SELECT CAST('0000-00-00' AS DATE) IS NULL;
```

The result of above query is **False**, so only it displays as **0**